# SqlException(0x80131904): "connection was recovered and rowcount in the first query is not available"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, claims

I get an exception in my ASP.NET MVC app, the error does not always happen, but when it happens, this is the error that I get when trying to read information from the database

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The connection was
>   recovered and rowcount in the first query is not available. Please
>   execute another query to get a valid rowcount.

The error only occurs on the publish version

I am using a DB from Windows Azure and claims to authenticate

Answer (score 4):

I solved this error message with:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

before executing the query that required a subsequent @@ROWCOUNT result.